# Rich Text Format RTF codec for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Anyone know of any library that will enable me to read/write RTF format files on the iPhone? NSAttributedString would be the way to go - but since that isn't available just yet :-(

Essentially I need to convert between simple text and RTF.

Answer (score 2):

The RTF file format is pretty simple. So if you just need to generate RTF from simple plain text the you can just generate an RTF file by hand.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format to start.