# How to create and save a .rtf, .doc, .docx in Objective-C for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, rtf, docx, doc

I am looking to create and save either a rtf, doc or docx file on an iPad (iOS).

The scenario is that we'd like to assist a user in creating content on their iPad and then let them email this as an editable document cross-platform (OS X, WIN).

I am open to other solutions besides the rtf, doc or docx file format.

Thanks,

James

Comment: What did you tried, what kind of support would you like for these formats, etc... Please post some details, and concrete examples if you need help...

Comment: I currently do not have an example. I am looking for a strategy before I code. My first strategy was to follow the open standards of the docx format, but on my initial investigations it proved overly complex for my needs. I have looked for any documentation, examples with the google and have not had any luck.

I found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105%28office.12%29.aspx but it wasn't much help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RTF is going to be the easiest, because it's a plain text format. It's kind of like HTML, but without closing tags.  [Here](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/RTF) is a class for writing an RTF, but it requires a lot of dependencies from elsewhere in the framework.

DOCX would be rather difficult. It's actually a zip file, containing a few XML files.  You can examine the format yourself by changing the .docx extension to .zip and unzipping it. But even though XML is a fairly easy to write format, the way the text attributes are organized is still rather complicated. Also, I recall that it has to be zipped in a very specific way to be read properly.

As for DOC, it will be very difficult because it's such a complex format. You could look into some open source projects, like [Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/) or [Word2x](http://sourceforge.net/projects/word2x/). Be careful using their code because the licenses may not agree with the App Store rules.

Comment: Thanks, looks like rtf is it.

Comment: Your GitHub link is dead; is it possible to include the answer in the answer, rather than as a link.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen doc & docx readers for iPhone ([App store entry linked here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-word-excel-file-viewer/id331933924?mt=8)), but I don't know of any open source frameworks you can make use of.

RTF format should be pretty simple to write, if you're up to the challenge.  There is no built in framework support for it ([here's a related question, b.t.w.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347149/rich-text-format-rtf-codec-for-iphone)).

Maybe you could write out something in a regular TEXT format and e-mail that?

Comment: I haven't found any iOS open source apps either. The doc I would like to write is fairly complex so I was hoping for something a little more ready baked. Unfortunately the formatting is also important. Thanks.

Comment: That app most likely uses a UIWebView which has built in support for displaying many file formats, such as .doc and .docx. (It has no support for editing/saving, though.)

Answer (score 0):

[Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) has a cloud service that you can reach from iOS.  You can ask it to render a doc in various formats (doc, rtf, pdf, odt etc) and email it off or stream it back - though you have to be connected.  Previewing DOC on iOS is possible but a little flaky.  One option is to stream PDF back for display on iOS and email editable document (which can be done in one call).