# How to convert .html into .docx in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on editor application. I am able to create editor & I generated html file from
RichText using webView. Now client wants to save this html file into .docx format. 
I searched too much in iOs sdk to convert .html into .docx but could not found any help.
During search I found following link

http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/

This is a php file.
Now I want integrate this file in my xcode.
Now my problem is that how I integrate this php code file in iOs?
OR is there any other option to generate .docx file from .html file in iOs?

Any help or idea would be geat.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look [there][1] : a similar discussion.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235532/how-to-create-and-save-a-rtf-doc-docx-in-objective-c-for-ios

Comment: Thanks LudoZik, I have tried this but could not get anything that can help.